# it's possible to upload a video directly to Vimeo from a form in my application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http, file-upload, vimeo

I have an application where the users can upload their videos. What I need is a way to upload those videos directly to my Vimeo account without have to upload to my server first.

What I have been trying is the example form the docs, in where you can use a form that posts directly to the endpoint. This works fine but I can't receive the response in my application in order to complete the upload with the video_id that comes in the response. When the upload is complete, I'm being redirected to a Vimeo page that says 'Thanks for uploading!'. I believe that there isn't a callback for this action in the API configuration.

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I Highly recommend you do not use the Advanced API. The new Beta API is about to leave beta, and is very stable.

Check out the upload docs for POST uploading https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload#http-post-uploading through a form and make sure you include every piece. The important section is the "redirect_uri".

This URI is where your user will be sent to once the upload is complete along with a "video_uri" parameter in the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to change the TYPE When you create a link to upload POST?
I used the TYPE until last Friday successfully in streaming.
This week you have a similar phenomenon occurred.
So I resolved to change the TYPE to POST.